# Clickonce exe blocked

Tags: clickonce

Trying to deploy application using ClickOnce to a webserver running sharepoint. I can publish it to my local IIS but when i try on the external server i get.

> Error    1   Failed to copy file 'D:\PROJECT\xxxx\poc\Setup\WpfClickOnce\WpfClickOnce\bin\Debug\app.publish\setup.exe' to 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx/clickonce/setup.exe'. Unable to add 'setup.exe' to the Web site.  Server error: The following file(s) have been blocked by the administrator: setup.exe

Im using Admin password and admin on VS and have added mime types to webserver but still does not work, any ideas

Comment: Found answer. As installation folder is inside sharepoint application its subject to a blocking list. I can turn of exe files, but i would not recommend it. Details can be found here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288335(office.12).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it and it was a sharepoint problem. As i put the installation folder inside the sharepoint appliction its subject to sharep

This article gives details
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288335(office.12).aspx